USB drives in space?
The question of laptops has been brought up; the classic answer is here:
What kind of laptops do ISS astronauts use?
On a tangential note - do they have or use USB drives for any reason?   With networked machines, you may not need them at all.  Or are there special cases where they are needed?

Here's a USB drive with an interesting story - it was dropped from the ISS so it could return to Earth on its own!  and here's another! Somewhat related: Are Solid State Hard Drives in space made from radiation-hardened FLASH memory, or do they just use older technology with higher voltage and charge?

Never underestimate the bandwidth of a reentry vehicle full of USB drives hurtling down the gravity well...

I’m pretty sure this made it to HNQ because everybody thinks this is the sequel to Pigs in Space :-)

Suggest title change to "USB drives in zero gravity" or "in orbit" because "in space" made me think it was "in vacuum" and I started thinking about cold-welding on insertion, etc.

USB drives are being used. The uplink and downlink bandwidth to the ISS are limited, and thus solid state storage offers an unmatched bandwidth especially for data retrieval. Thus one of the common usages is that astronouts do attach or remove USB drives to which experiments dump their data. Later they will be shipped back to Earth, possibly along with a crew exchange.
This is a (slightly edited) excerpt from the operations manual of the experiment I'm currently building for the ISS. The experiment is capable of generating data in excess of 1TB/day, and our bandwidth is limited to a guaranteed 4MBit with the option to sometimes get 50MBit (depending on availability) - so a retrieval via network copy is (sadly) not an option:

5.2 Crew Operations
As already mentioned, the Insert is mainly operated from ground via the ESA MPCC data link connectivity and the ICMCC provided secure data communication link towards the user home base. The intervention of the crew is only requested for:

Initial installation and final removal of the Insert (and external cables and hoses);
Collection of data in removable USB drives for physical download to ground.
Toggling the switches (in case science operations have to pause for other campaigns)


I'm right now unable to quickly find the exact model used; but it's a standard SSD as anyone can buy as external hard drive. Mind though, this all deals by no means with anything critical regarding to the ISS itself; it's just a plug & play payload, and there is more bandwidth available for mission-critical purposes.

Are there any special considerations for data loss or damage? Especially considering the high-radiation environment of the ISS. Do they copy the same data to multiple SSDs with checksums for all relevant files?

Astronauts are exposed to 144 mSv a year1 ; good quality commercial SSDs fail around 70-500 mSv 2, implying that this is potentially mitigatable if the SSDs are not in orbit for large numbers of months, but is likely to be a problem for longer experiments.

@Michael in this particular case no special consideration is done. The potentially most-interesting data are pre-selected by an onboard algorithm and downloaded within the available bandwidth. The remainder stored on the SSDs. As long as not the whole device fails, an upset within a single acquired image is not critical damage to the data either. It's a short-duration mission with an estimate of 9 month duration overall so that David McKee's argument wrt short-duration missions applies.

One of the few instances where the "down" in download really means "down".

However the onboard data-storage does have redundancy by using a proper raid setup (but that's not USB). Thus the export of this storage on the external hard disks is somewhat the last step in which they are filled with data, and then brought back a short time later to Earth, reducing the sensitive time further.

Never underestimate the bandwidth of a rocket full of USB drives hurtling towards the Earth at super sonic speeds.

@planetmaker: Is it common for experiments to generate forward-error-correction data (e.g. in a .par2 file) so errors in blocks can be detected and corrected if the totals size of blocks with errors is smaller than the amount of (still-good) recovery data?  Running software like PAR2 is also something that can be done on the computer when the data is first copied to it, before it's had long to rot.  edit: Oh, I guess not on USB itself, you were replying to Michael asking if they checksum or duplicate.  RAID6(?) makes sense for their SSDs that USB sticks get copied to; double-redundancy.

Audio CDs contain something like 30% data adn 70% redundancy to allow CDs to play even with scratches.... I would assume experimental data which literally costs years of human labor and millions of dollars will be protected at least as well... I assume they probably use multiple disks and files/filesystems in use will have a high level of error correction.

This primary source is already pretty out of date (dated for 2011), but the answer to What paper size do they use on the International Space Station? included a Cargo Mission Contract solicitation that includes a detailed manifest of cargo to be shipped to the space station.  On page 421, Table 1-1.D Laptops, item 150 is "2 GB LIGHTING [sic] FLASHDRIVES".
A number of other storage devices are in the tables as well, including portable hard drives and SD cards (presumably for the cameras in the manifest).
It's not clear to me if the expanded storage available on the ZBooks versus the old A31s, plus the astronauts having iPads, etc, has completely obviated using portable USB drives on the space station or not.  I do know the software I delivered for ISS was delivered via network fileshare as late as 2018; my predecessor had the distinction of delivering software updates personally to one of the Space Shuttles (for a program that ran on one of the laptops) on a 3.5" floppy disk.

Delivering things on 3.5" floppy disks is what used to be fondly referred to as sneakernet.

Same in the film and broadcast industry, sneakernet was how we got tapes and reels sent round. I guess these days its for coffee runs...

We used to boot the terminal cluster controllers for the shuttle simulator off an 8" floppy. And this went on well into the 90s. Those things were guarded like treasure.

@OrganicMarble ...and at one time Kermit was used on the ISS to move data before otherwise-incompatible systems. I'd suggest that the only issue with USB is deciding "which side is up" when plugging the damn things in in microgravity :-)

@MarkMorganLloyd  - good one. Although what interests me is that when I was a kid in the 1960’s we were always told how there is no up and down in space, and you would see drawings of inside a space station with workstations in different areas upside down or sideways. But as it turned out we do better with some vertical orientation, so for the most part people on ISS seem to be working with their feet towards nadir, unless they have a specific need to be "upside down" or horizontal. And generally much of the equipment seems to be installed based on the nadir side being "down".

@StevePemberton I believe the notable exception is the cupola, where the head position needed to see outside makes nadir "up". At least as far as foot restraints and laptop orientations and the robotics workstation, etc. But see also the interior design of Galina Balashova for the Soviets http://kvadratinterwoven.com/out-of-this-world-the-space-age-designs-of-galina-balashova
